# Parsing xml files in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I am developing an android app using code from a normal java application.
In this java application i am parsing an XML file which i get like this:

```
File xmlFile = new File("../project/src/resources/words.xml");
```

Now in android this doesn't seem to work. I get a file not found exception.
I tried to save the file in the `res/xml` directory but I'm not sure how to get to it.

Can i use the same code to parse the XML as I used for my java application or is there a special way to parse XML files in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `../project/src/resources.words.xml`? Is that a pathname in your project directory on your development machine? Of course an Android program is not going to have access to file paths defined on your machine.

If `words.xml` is a static file that you'd like access to, you should include it in the `/res/raw` subdirectory of your project. Then you can access it using the methods described in the documentation here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource(int)

Or, you can put it in `/assets` and use this method:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html

Comment: I used the /assets method and it worked with my old xml parsing methods

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(resourceId);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
... then read the content of the file as a stream ...
```

Your file must be placed in `res/raw/yourfile` and `resourceId` is an integer in `R.raw...` corresponding to your filename (`R.raw.yourfile`)